# Autofac with Owin

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, owin, autofac

I have an issue with **Autofac**. The documentation clearly states that when using Web API 2 and OWIN you **must not** use `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration` anywhere:

> A common error in OWIN integration is use of the GlobalConfiguration.Configuration. In OWIN you create the configuration from scratch. You should not reference GlobalConfiguration.Configuration anywhere when using the OWIN integration.

which can be found here (at the bottom of the page): http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html

But no matter what I do, I can not get **Autofac** to work using:

```
config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

instead of:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

When I use the latter, it works.
Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out. I will post the answer here incase anyone else has this issue.
As the documentation stated, you can't use `GlobalConfiguration` anywhere....
so I did a search and I found it somewhere else.
I had this:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

which should have been:

```
WebApiConfig.Register(config);
```

When I fixed that, I was able to use the proper

```
config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```